# Send textarea not with form

Tags: html, forms, textarea

I have a textarea for search input. Its in a bigger `form`:

```
<form action method ...>
  <stuff>
  //search with <textarea>
  <stuff
  <button submit>
</form>
```

so i cant `POST` the search with the ordinary:

```
<form action... method...>
   <textarea>
   <button submit>
</form>
//shortened
```

because `<form>`s cant stack like `<div>`s

How can i send the searchquery to my php server with a `<a>` or else?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use preventDefault like so:

```
<textarea id='lone-text' placeholder='Type in your search query'></textarea><br>
<a href='#' id='lone-text-submit' onclick='event.preventDefault(); submitTextarea()'>Search Textarea Only</a>

<script>
function submitTextarea(){
    //Use Ajax To Send To PHP
}
</script>
```